# Using interface to leverage basic Unity methods?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My idea is to remove Monobehavior scripts that are there only because I need to do a one time task, like assigning an event in their "Start" method or initialize an object,..

Is it okay to create an interface with basic methods (Awake,Start,..) and call all objects from my only Monobehavior?

here is my full example:

```
public interface IMain {

    void OnMyAwake();
    void OnMyStart();
    void OnMyUpdate();
}


private void Awake()
{
    Debug.Log("I'm awake");

    for (int x = 0; x < list.Length; x++) {

        list[x].OnMyAwake();

    }
}


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    Debug.Log("I'm Start");

    for (int x = 0; x < list.Length; x++)
    {

        list[x].OnMyStart();

    }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    for (int x = 0; x < list.Length; x++)
    {

        list[x].OnMyUpdate();

    }
}
```

Thoughts about this approach?

Comment: [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) my be a better forum for your particular question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that `Awake()` can not be called before `list[0..n-1]` are all defined, or include something to handle that case properly

Once that is taken care of, this should work as you expect (timing-wise).

You might also want to include `OnDestroy` and `OnDisable` methods.